# WooCommerce Paypal Iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, paypal, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce plugin and Paypal Express checkout for the payment. Everything is working fine till now. Now I got a new domain and I put domain as GoDaddy Masking and thus it loads the Main site in an iframe. The site loads fine, but the checkout is not working as Paypal doesn't supports iframe.

Opening the paypal redirect link in a new tab works fine. So I put target="_blank" for the checkout form, but as the form submission is ajax and target="_blank" not handled in WooCommerce js, it doesn't work.

Is there any work around? Please let us know your suggestions.

Answer (score -3):

Using javascript you can open payapal page in another tab

```
<script>
function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
</script>
<a onclick="OpenInNewTab();">Paypal link</a>
```